# Ajaxifying Joomla 1.5/2.5 template

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

It is a most widely used feature in websites. But i never found somebody done it on Joomla site. All i need is ajaxify Joomla website. Ie; No page load for site navigation. I have done this in wordpress successfully. But tried to port the code and no luck. Modded the code like hell still no good news. Can any one help me on this. This is the tutorial i used to ajaxify wordpress.

http://goo.gl/97TZA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try this extension:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/scripts/13293

I have never tested it before so can't tell you how good it is, but judging by the reviews, it does a really good job. For this extension to work, you template has to be written using the Joomla standards, however it won't work with some components and plugins, but nevertheless, give it a try and let me know how it is.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It almost looks like my requirement. Only problem i found was it is not available for 1.5. It is ok. Thanks again. Cheers